# Set background color and image to canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

The following code will set background color and image to the canvas but I cant able to resize the uploaded image.

`var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');` 
//To set canvas background color
 `canvas.setBackgroundColor('rgba(255,255,255,255)',canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);`

//To upload background image

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('upload-bgfile');
        imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
         function handleImage(e) {  
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (event){
          var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center',
                    left: 300,
                    top: 100,   
                });
            };  

            img.src = event.target.result;

          } 

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

        }   
        canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: Add `width` and `height` properties to the options to `setBackgroundImage`

Answer (score 0):

you should refer code below,

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor({source: 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/escheresque_ste.png'}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

for more: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/hXzvk/